# Themes not showing up in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, pysimplegui

There's this problem for me in PySimpleGUI where it doesn't show me the theme I want.
I tried several themes and it presented me with dark mode. Can anyone help?

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def create_window(theme):
    sg.theme("LightGrey1")
    sg.set_options(font= "Franklin 14", button_element_size = (6,3))
    button_size = (6,3)
    layout = [
        [sg.Text("output", font= "Franklin 26", justification= "right", expand_x= True, pad= (10,20))],
        [sg.Button(7, size= button_size), sg.Button(8, size= button_size), sg.Button(9, size= button_size), sg.Button("*", size= button_size)],
        [sg.Button(4, size= button_size), sg.Button(5, size= button_size), sg.Button(6, size= button_size), sg.Button("/", size= button_size)],
        [sg.Button(1, size= button_size), sg.Button(2, size= button_size), sg.Button(3, size= button_size), sg.Button("-", size= button_size)],
        [sg.Button(0, expand_x= True), sg.Button(".", size= button_size), sg.Button("+", size= button_size),],
]

    return sg.Window("Calculator", layout)

window = create_window("dark")


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break


window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

In following code, `"dark"` passed as argument of function `create_window`, but not used in the function `create_window`.

```py
def create_window(theme):
    sg.theme("LightGrey1")             # Always in "LightGrey1" here
...
    return sg.Window("Calculator", layout)

window = create_window("DarkBlue4")    # For example in "DarkBlue4"
```

It should be

```py
def create_window(theme):
    sg.theme(theme)
...
    return sg.Window("Calculator", layout)

window = create_window("DarkBlue4")    # Set the theme for your window here
```